# Change HTML value based on typescript value

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular, I'm trying to set a value to an input using typescript to an HTML input, it is working fine however, when I submit the form it reads the value as an empty string, if I typed anything in the input in addition to the value that has been set the from submits with the value successfully, but doesn't submit if the value is set without changing anything manually, please advise if there is a better approach or how to correct this, thanks in advance.

**company.component.html**

```
<input type="text" id="LogoImageUrl" formControlName="LogoImageUrl">
```

**company.component.ts**

```
this.editCompanyForm = this.fb.group({
 LogoImageUrl: new FormControl({ value: ''})
})

this.image = (
  <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("LogoImageUrl")
).value = this.imageUrl


uploadFile(file) {
const contentType = file.type;
const bucket = new S3(
      {
          accessKeyId: 'key',
          secretAccessKey: 'key',
          region: 'region'
      }
  );
  const params = {
      Bucket: 'name',
      Key: 'url' + file.name,
      Body: file,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      ContentType: contentType
  };
  bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {


      if (err) {
          console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
          return false;
      }
      console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
      return true;
  }); 
  bucket.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function (evt) {
      console.log(evt.loaded + ' of ' + evt.total + ' Bytes');
  }).send(function (err, data) {

      if (err) {
          console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
          return false;
      }
      this.imageUrl = data.Location;
      this.editCompanyForm.patchValue({
        'LogoImageUrl': this.imageUrl
      });  
      return true;
  });

  }
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: I have updated my code, please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use arrow function for s3 instance to bind current component this context.

**Try this:**

**component.ts**

```
uploadFile(file) {
const contentType = file.type;
const bucket = new S3(
      {
          accessKeyId: 'key',
          secretAccessKey: 'key',
          region: 'region'
      }
  );
  const params = {
      Bucket: 'name',
      Key: 'url' + file.name,
      Body: file,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      ContentType: contentType
  };
  bucket.upload(params,(err, data)=> { 
      if (err) {
          console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
          return false;
      }
      console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
      return true;
  }); 
  bucket.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', (evt)=>{
      console.log(evt.loaded + ' of ' + evt.total + ' Bytes');
  }).send(()=> (err, data) {

      if (err) {
          console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
          return false;
      }
      this.imageUrl = data.Location;
      this.editCompanyForm.patchValue({
        'LogoImageUrl': this.imageUrl
      });  
      return true;
  });

  }
```

Comment: Are you getting same erro?

Comment: It finally worked, I can't thank you enough my friend

Comment: Glad to help my friend!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
this.editCompanyForm.controls["LogoImageUrl"].setValue(this.imageUrl);
```

A form control instance provides a setValue() method that updates the value of the form control. You can look at https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: I've tried this and it is coming up with ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

Comment: and this ? this.editCompanyForm.get('LogoImageUrl').setValue(this.imageUrl);

Comment: unfortunately came up with the same "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Comment: and  this.editCompanyForm.patchValue({
   LogoImageUrl: this.imageUrl
});   ?  your editCompanyForm is initialized? if it's still not ok, could you provide your complete code please

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'patchValue' of undefined

Comment: do you have a  <form [formGroup]="editCompanyForm">   in your template?

Comment: I have updated my code, please check it out, I guess the problem is that I am mixing typescript inside a javascript method, could that be the case ?, because when I tried your suggested answer outside this method it worked fine
this.editCompanyForm.patchValue({
        'LogoImageUrl': this.imageUrl
      });

Comment: Yes, it is a class Object

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the formbuilder in the ngOnInit ()? If you have not done so, it will give you undefined.

Comment: Yes, I have initialized it

Comment: try .  --->  LogoImageUrl: [' ']  and use this.editCompanyForm.controls.LogoImageUrl.setValue(this.imageUrl);

Comment: the problem presists in controls,,,it is coming up with undefined